# How to fix error when working with Calendar Component of react-date-range

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working with Calendar component of [react-date-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range) but I have seen following error.
[image]

This is simple code I using.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';

    export default class App extends Component {
      handeeSelect(date) {
        console.log(date);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Calendar
              onInit={this.handeeSelect}
              onChange={this.handeeSelect}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I assume you have imported 
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';`

Comment: Is this component also using react-native? i.e. `import { Text, View } from 'react-native';`

Comment: yes, i imported modules

Comment: Calendar is component of react-date-range not react-native

Comment: I am aware, I also cannot see what the imports are... So I can't assume.

Comment: I literally can see only what you have posted...

Comment: Can you show me the whole file `imports` and all

Comment: Great thanks! That might help solve this :)

Comment: i edited in my question @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, the issue revolved around the library in use. Either the linking to the Native code or the library was causing compatibility issues. Be sure to link libraries you add to native code when adding new ones.

I think you need to wrap the calendar component in a `div` because React-Native View is weird and needs a child element.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';



   export default class App extends Component {
  handeeSelect(date) {
    console.log(date);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <div>
          <Calendar onInit={this.handeeSelect} onChange={this.handeeSelect} />
        </div>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope this works. I remember React-Native being finicky on some things.

Comment: I changed code like you, but it still same error :(

Comment: @TuyenNH Dang, I hope it isn't an issue with the library. Did you "link" the library to the "native" code?

Comment: yes, i linked the library to the native code. This is the first time i using it so i don't know it is issue of the library

Comment: Hi @Jacob,  i think this issue casue is the library, thanks you helped

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to upvote and mark the edited answer as resolved. @TuyenNH